# Se puede eliminar el trail de la bola?

Tags: java

```
Ansi.clearScreen();
        printFrame(' ', COL, ROW, NUM_COLS, NUM_ROWS, Ansi.Color.NONE, Ansi.Color.YELLOW);

        while(true) {      
        Ansi.printTo('O', ballX, ballY, false, Ansi.Color.NONE, Ansi.Color.NONE);
                
            ballX += dirX;
            ballY += dirY;
            Util.wait(delay); 

        }
    }

    public static void printFrame(char c, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, Ansi.Color fg, Ansi.Color bg)  {
        for(int x = xPos; x <= xPos + width - 1; x++) {
            Ansi.printTo(c, x, yPos, false, fg, bg);
            Ansi.printTo(c, x, yPos + height - 1, false, fg, bg);
        }

        for(int y = yPos; y <= yPos + height - 1; y++) {
            Ansi.printTo(c, xPos, y, false, fg, bg);
            Ansi.printTo(c, xPos + width - 1, y, false, fg, bg);
        }
    }
}
```

He hecho este programa que imprime una bola 'O' dento de un cuadrado acotado, y mi duda consiste en si es posible eliminar el rastro que deja dicha bola al volver a imprimirse por el bucle while.

Comment: no entiendo, cual rastro???

Comment: A lrastro me refiero a la rayectoria que dibuya la bola, me gustaria que solo apareciese la bola en si

Comment: no logro ver el rastro ni la bola ...